# Почему происходит ошибка "syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '" и не получается указать параметры функции"?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, openserver, синтаксис

Всем добрый день! Я только начинаю изучать программирование и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
```

Ссылается на строку с этим кодом:

```
sum(a:4, b:9, c: '+');
```

Сама функция:

```
<?php
function sum($a, $b, $s = '+'){
    if ($s == '*') {
        echo $a * $b;
    }
    elseif ($s == '+'){
        echo $a + $b;
    }
    elseif ($s == '-'){
        echo $a - $b;
    }
    elseif ($s == '/'){
        echo $a / $b;
    }
}

sum(a: 4, b: 5, s: '+');
```

Я не могу понять, где именно у меня ошибка. В учебнике, где я нашёл значение эту функции, а также в видео-уроке - всё работало, но у меня не работает.

Я подозреваю что у меня какая-то другая версия php.
`phpversion()` отображает `7.4.30`.
Я использую `Open Server` - там версия php в настройках `PHP_7.4`.
Также использую VS Code (Версия: 1.76.2 (user setup))

Урок, с которого я переписал эту функцию был снят 2 года назад, если это имеет значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так или хотя бы куда мне копать дальше, чтобы исправить эту проблему?

Comment: @Зонтик, названия программ не нужно выделять как фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именованные аргументы в php появились в версии 8.0.
Можете либо обновиться до более новой версии, либо перепишите код без именованных аргументов:

```
sum(4, 5, '+');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно заработало)  @RoTar
Пока ещё не очень понимаю, как те или иные версии PHP отличаются друг от друга, очень полезно, помогли